# uploading video to youtube with jhipster?

Tags: oauth, youtube, video-streaming, jwt, jhipster

I'm working on a jhipster application, I want to upload videos to a youtube channel, so is it necessary to work with Oauth security to connect to google or can I work with jwt authentication?

Comment: It depends on whether your users will have their own youtube channel, if this is not the case then there should be no relation with JHipster auth mechanism.

Comment: I want users to upload their video in my private channel, so they don't need to connect to google !!

Comment: OK, so your users will upload videos to your backend app and then your app will upload them to YouTube using your API key. So there's nothing specific to JHipster here, no dependency on JHipster authentication mechanism.